# Check if last message is fetched with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Check if all messages are fetched.

I'll have a PDO MySQL query to fetch private messsages for the user.
The user might have many messages, so I use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. The whole thing will be fetched with AJAX.
The typical query (in a simplified form) will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM planz_messages AS m 
LEFT JOIN planz_users AS users_from 
ON m.user_from=users_from.id 
WHERE (user_from = :user_id OR user_to = :user_id) ORDER BY time_delivered
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

The interface will contain a button "Load more messages" and I need to hide it when the last message is fetched.

So what's the best way (performance and elegancy-wise) to know whether the last row of the query is fetched?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering the best way to check if each batch has records remaining, then it's standard to check of `fetch()` is returning false.

I'd you're wondering if the batch overall will return rows, then it's pretty standard to issue a `select count (*)` query.